# Parametric Resonance Analysis using Perturbative approach

Tags: non-linear-systems, anharmonic-oscillators

I'm reading Parametric Resonance from Landau's Mechanics Text. A similar calculation is done [here](https://galileoandeinstein.phys.virginia.edu/7010/CM_20_Parametric_Resonance.html). Supposing a parametric oscillator given by
$$\ddot{x}(t)+\omega_0^2(1+h\cos(\gamma t))x(t)=0$$
It's said that near the resonance $\gamma=2\omega_0+\epsilon$, We have a solution of the form:
$$x(t)=a(t)\cos\left(\omega_0+\frac{\epsilon}{2}\right)t+b(t)\sin\left(\omega_0+\frac{\epsilon}{2}\right)t$$
with  $a(t)$ and $b(t)$ being a slowly varying function. They work out in first order in $\epsilon$ and first-order in $h$. What I'm saying is why we don't solve the problem with the perturbative approach and writing the function as power series in $h$?

Here's How I did it? First, We can write the equation as
$$\ddot{x}+\omega_0^2(1+he^{i\gamma t})x=0$$
Up to first order in $h$,
$$\ddot{x_0}+\omega_0^2 x_0(t)=0\rightarrow x_0(t)=Ae^{i\omega_0 t}$$
Up to first order:
$$\ddot{x}_1(t)+\omega_0^2(1+he^{i\gamma t})x_0(t)=0\rightarrow x_1(t)=\frac{\omega_0^2A}{(\omega_0+\gamma)^2}he^{i(\omega_0+\gamma)t}+Ae^{i\omega t}$$

Putting $\gamma=2\omega_0+\epsilon$,
$$x_1(t)=\frac{\omega_0^2A}{(3\omega_0+\epsilon)^2}he^{i(3\omega_0+\epsilon)t}+Ae^{i\omega t}\approx \frac{A}{9}\left(1-\frac{2\epsilon}{3\omega_0}\right)he^{i(3\omega_0+\epsilon)t}+Ae^{i\omega t}$$
This is different than what written by Landau. Why this doesn't work?

Comment: The parameter that affected the frequency is $\Omega$ not h. see pendulum example

Comment: So should I write the perturbation series in $\gamma$?

Comment: notice that $e^{i\,\gamma\,t}=\cos(\gamma\,t)+i\,\sin(\gamma\,t)~$ thus you obtain the solution that gave in the paper

Comment: I don't understand, what are you saying? I have written it that way for simplification why I would change this back. Can you please write an answer? How this problem can be solved with perturbation?